# Abnormal display

Tags: graphics, display, gpu-driver

I just installed Ubuntu with VM Virtual Box on Mac.
After I ran Ubuntu first time, I have a disply as attached.

Can you help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by the 3D Acceleration option.

1. Open VirtualBox
2. Open the "Settings" for your Ubuntu VM
3. Click on "Display" on the left hand side
4. Remove the check from "Enable 3D Acceleration" (as seen in the image below)

[image]

Restart the VM.  This should fix the issue.  If not, you may need to reinstall Ubuntu in the VM again.

Comment: Thanks. It was Ubuntu14.04. I had no problem on Ubuntu16.10.